# Multiline command-line editing in Gforth console

Tags: forth, gforth

I have just started learning the Forth programming language.
I'm using Gforth on Ubuntu. In Gforth interactive console, I want to do indentation but it requires changing line. Enter key didn't work, it executed code. For comparison, for example, when one tests JavaScript code in web browser console, shift+enter change line without executing code. I want something like that. What key should I press?  Is there a way other than using text editors like vim?
Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gforth doesn't support multiline editing (see the [manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Command_002dline-editing.html)).

A workaround is to edit a file in your favorite editor in another window and reload this file in Gforth console as:

```
include /tmp/scratch.fs
```

An external file can be also edited in Gforth console via a command like:

```
"vim /tmp/scratch.fs" system
```

So a one-liner for that is:

```
"vim /tmp/scratch.fs" system  "/tmp/scratch.fs" included
```

That can be wrapped into a definition as:

```
: scratch "vim /tmp/scratch.fs" system  "/tmp/scratch.fs" included ;
```

So the word `scratch` will open an editor and than load the edited file.

NB: if you use a quite old build of Gforth, you have to use `s" ccc"` instead of `"ccc"` for string literals.

To conditionally include/exclude some parts in a file the words [`[defined]`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/BracketDEFINED) and [`[if]`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/BracketIF) can be used; to erase the previous instance of the loaded definitions the word [`marker`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/MARKER) can be used as:

```
[defined] _clear [if] _clear [then]
marker _clear

\ some definitions
\ ...
```

Take into account that usual control-flow words can be used in definitions only.